# Запрос логина и пароля при подключении через PDO

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Подключаюсь к БД стандартными средствами PDO

```
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'test';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_pass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('pdo connection error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы для подключения к моей базе переменные

```
$db_user = ''; 
$db_pass = '';
```

требовалось вводить сразу при открытии страницы? Чтобы содержимое базы не выводилось на экран, если у пользователя нет соответствующих прав

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируешь сессию и проверяешь наличие ключа в ней. Если его нет, то выводишь форму ввода из двух полей для твоих переменных. Отправляешь ее `$_POST` на этот же файл (или другой), где производишь проверку достоверности и инициализируешь подключение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать страницу login_db.php:

```
<form action="connection.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" required /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" required />< br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Логин" />
</form>
```

Тогда, припустим что ваш код подключения, который вы кинули, находится в файле connection.php:

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'test';


try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $_POST['user'], $_POST['password']);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('pdo connection error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Валидацию полей и css думаю сделаете уже сами :)

А еще можно JS использовать. Просто при загрузке показываете alert и с помощью JS считываете эти же поля.